# Do angels have fixed Incepts?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

The Demon Storyteller Guide introduces the game-changing power of angelic Incepts. However, none of the sample angels written up in the guide have assigned Incepts, although they do have specific Numina.

Do angels have specific Incepts as part of the character description?  Or can an angel invoke any Incept she needs at a given time (up to the maximum number allowed by her Rank)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Incepts are intended to be fixed

Incepts are only described in one section of the *Storyteller's Guide*, so our information on them comes from such.

> Each angel **has** a number of Incepts equal to its Rank.

Page 83, emphasis mine.

If Incepts could be accessed as needed, the passage might instead say "can choose" or "can employ", specifying when and what conditions would allow Incepts to be "swapped out" (eg, end of scene, if not in use.)

Furthermore, consider Influences:

> [Angels] begin with dots in Influence equal to their Rank.

DtD, Page 343

And Manifestations:

> [Angels] begin with the Twilight Form Manifestation and a number of Manifestation Effects from the list below equal to Rank.

DtD, Page 345

Numina follows the same pattern on Page 349; all state that Angels have a discrete set of these powers, implying that they are permanent fixtures on their sheets, instead of dynamically assigned. Because Incepts uses verbiage that implies ownership rather than access ("has" rather than "can use"), it makes sense that Incepts are intended to be fixed.

It is understandable that example Angels found outside of the *Storyteller's Guide* would not reference this material, but it is unfortunate that no examples within this book offer a concrete example of an Angel's Incepts. The Superintendent would have been an excellent choice, but he is built before the section on Incepts.